# Send Image and DTO from Retrofit to Spring

Tags: android, spring, spring-boot, retrofit, retrofit2

I want to send from android retrofit a file and a DTO to a Spring Boot Server. I use Mutlipart with RequestBody.  But so how i configured the api from the server, the server don't react to the call of the android app. Is my api from the server wrong?

My API from the server is:

```
@PostMapping("images/{id}")
@ResponseBody
fun addImage(@RequestPart("file") file: MultipartFile, @RequestPart("dto") objDto:ObjectDto, @PathVariable id:Int) :FileDto?
```

The API from the android app is:

```
@POST("images/{id}")
@Multipart
fun addImage(@Part("file")file: okhttp3.RequestBody, @Part("dto") dto: ObjectDto, @Path("id") id:Int) : Call<FileDto?>
```

From the Client i call with retrofit the server with this code

```
...
val file = imageFiles.get(0).file
val imageBody = RequestBody.create(MultipartBody.FORM, file)
call.addImage(imageBody, ObjectDto(3,"Test", "dfgd", "adfas", "ada",4,4,"adg", Date(0), 3,4,null,null),2)
                .enqueue(object: Callback<FileDto?> {
                override fun onFailure(call: Call<FileDto?>, t: Throwable) {
                    t.printStackTrace()
                }

                override fun onResponse(call: Call<FileDto?>, response: Response<FileDto?>) {

                    TODO("not implemented") //To change body of created functions use File | Settings | File Templates.
                }
            })
```

Comment: In your Retrofit API interface, `addImage()` method first argument should be of type `MultipartBody.Part` not `RequestBody`. From where did you refer that code?

Comment: How would you know if the call succeeds?  Your `onResponse` function doesn't do anything.

Comment: @Shashanth i changed it, but it didn't work. someone tell me that

Comment: @nasch i have authentication that is react to mine call